# Toggle TeX-fold-mode using a key binding

Tags: auctex

How can I toggle the `auctex` facility `TeX-fold-mode` using `C-c +`?

I have

```
(add-hook 'tex-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key (kbd "C-c +") 'TeX-fold-mode)))
```

But this is not working as intended, since I need to run `TeX-fold-buffer` too after reactivating `TeX-fold-mode`, otherwise nothing actually gets folded.

So I need to somehow define a function which turns `TeX-fold-mode` off if it's on or otherwise turns it on **and** runs `TeX-fold-buffer` at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minor modes (like `TeX-fold-mode`) usually define a variable of the same name that reflects in its value (`t` or `nil`) the state of the mode (enabled or disabled). You can query the variable but you should *NOT* set it: enabling or disabling the mode does that.

So you can define your function like this:

```el
(defun my/TeX-fold-mode-toggle ()
   (interactive)
   (if TeX-fold-mode      ;; if enabled  ...
      (TeX-fold-mode -1)  ;;      disable it
     (TeX-fold-mode 1)    ;; else enable it
     (TeX-fold-buffer)))   ;;     and fold the buffer
```

and you bind it with

```el
... (local-set-key (kbd "C-c +") #'my/TeX-fold-mode)
```

I hope it works but it is untested.

Comment: Excellent that works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Hint: Sequences consisting of C-c and a letter (either upper or lower case) are reserved for users; they are the only sequences reserved for users.  Sequences consisting of C-c followed by any other ASCII punctuation or symbol character are allocated for minor modes. [(Source)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Key-Binding-Conventions)